# Remove all active filters from sheet in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with tables in excel and I want to remove all filter that has been set in any of my 52 columns, remove bold, colors etc(back to normal formatting).

Somehow my code does not do this, any idea where the issue might be?

```
'Clears filters on the activesheet. Will not clear filters if the sheet is protected.
On Error Resume Next
If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.FilterMode Or ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
   ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If

 'in case the sheet is protected
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("List").Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.Cells.AutoFilter
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

Comment: `If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.AutoFilter
    End If
    If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If `         It does not trigger any of those if sentences..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this one instead:

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
```

It may work.

Comment: Thats what i have in my code that does not work for some reason.

Comment: it works, except that it does not removing sorting: ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below

```
Cells.AutoFilter
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved it:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("List").ListObjects("FilterParts").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

However how can I sort this column

```
Range("FilterParts[[#Headers],[POS NUMBER]]").Select
```

so that it shows everything except blanks?